# Show that for big objects only one particular path will contribute to the particle's motion.

Tags: quantum-mechanics

When i throw a tennis ball it doesn't take every possible path at once. It should according to QM, shouldn't it?

Comment: This is the classic (sorry) example used to demonstrate the path integral approach. You sum over all possible paths, and see that the phases interfere for the non-classical ones, leaving just the classical path of the ball. Whether that means it *is* taking all possible paths depends on your interpretation of quantum mechanics.

Comment: Is it possible to prove it mathematically?